# Controlling high rating DC motor

Tags: microcontroller, motor, integrated-circuit, dc-motor

In a robot, I need to use a (24 volts 5-7 amp) DC motor, which should be controlled by a microcontroller. Now, will I get a motor driver IC for such a motor? If not, what kind of circuit will help? I am new in robotics, so I will be very thankful for any diagram with explanation.

Comment: What voltage does your microcontroller use? Not the voltage that it is fed into the board, but the actual operating voltage of the chip. Is it 5V, 3.3V, something else? This will effect your choice of motor drive technology.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have much experience in building electronics, I recommend you to buy an already made driver. Pololu has a bunch of them, specially for DC motors: http://www.pololu.com/category/11/brushed-dc-motor-drivers

Anyway, I would like to know if the motor is a single-phase or a three-phase one, which application is it going to have... so I can help you further.

Comment: it is single phase

Comment: I found a quite simple MOSFET IC for building a DC driver ( https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Robotics/irf7862pbf.pdf )  and a simple tutorial http://www.instructables.com/id/Easy-DC-Motor-Controller/

Hope it helps!

Comment: I know this is going to sound seriously old-skool, but do consider using a relay for a serious motor like this. They cope with much more violence than most solid-state devices (eg stalls, transients, etc) and are much easier to deploy. Of course they have many downsides (bulky, noisy, slow). Of course, power MOSFETs, H-bridges, driver ICs, etc, are available to an experienced designer, but unless you are in the exciting world of power electronics (or want to enter it), and can aford a few molten devices, do conisder a relay at least for prototyping.

Comment: For use in robotics, I highly suggest avoiding relays. I agree with buying a Pololu motor driver which can do 30A peak and around 8-10A constant.. buy one for each motor.